# Powershell Regex to match domain\username

Tags: regex, parsing, tomcat, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to create a regular expression to match all usernames that make requests on a tomcat servers. A sample of the line from the logs:

192.10.123.45 - domain/username [30/Jul/2012:07:29:13 -0400] "GET /APP/ HTTP/1.1" 200 53167

The problem is there is a couple different formats for username :

1. Username
2. domain\username
3. domain/username

The current attempt:

```
if(($line -match “GET”) -AND ($line -match "(\s-\s\w{1,})")) {
            $temp = $matches[0]
            if(($line -match “GET”) -AND ($line -match "(\s-\s\w{1,}\S)?=[\\\/](w{1,}\b)")) {
                $temp1 = $matches[0]
                Write-host $temp
            }
```

I am using the space-space before the username as a starting point and that seems to be working fine. I always check if the line has "GET" in it because it is the only PHP call we care about for now. I have 2 matches because the first one will always just match one word, and if the second one is a match Ill use $temp to trim $temp1, because we do not care about the domain. What I am really having trouble with is how to say "Backslash OR Forwardslash" in terms of regex.

Also, I am not sure if my regex handles the case where a username will have numbers or the domain will have dashes. I am assuming this is picked up by \w but I cannot find any of these cases in development that I am testing in.

I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your questions, you want to be able to pull the domain\username out of a string of characters.  The following lines will pull out the usernames from what you have shown in your example:

```
$line = $line.split("-")[1]
$line = $line.split("[")[0]
$line = $line.trim()
```

This will leave `$line` with the value of `domain/username`

Now, for pulling out the username.

```
if ($line.Contains("/")) {
    $Line = $Line.split("/")[1]
} #End if($line.Contains("/")) {
if ($line.contains("\")) {
    $Line = $line.split("\")[1]
} #End if ($line.contains("\")) {
```

The end result will be `$line` containing username  This can be all wrapped in a search for GET

```
if (($line -match “GET”) {
    $Line = $Line.Replace(" - "," < ") 
    #If there is a - in the username, this replaces it so the split doesn't break up the username.  Change the < to suit whatever works best
    $line = $line.split("<")[1]
    $line = $line.split("[")[0]
    $line = $line.trim()
    if ($line.Contains("/")) {
        $Line = $Line.split("/")[1]
    } #End if($line.Contains("/")) {
    if ($line.contains("\")) {
        $Line = $line.split("\")[1]
    } #End if ($line.contains("\")) {
}#End if (($line -match “GET”) {
```

I tested with the line you put up there, and I ended up with `$line` equaling `username`.

After I answered this, I though maybe you wanted a regex for other uses.  So I wrote how to do this with regex as well:

```
if([regex]::Match($Line,".*GET.*").Success) {
        $line = [regex]::Split($Line,".*\s[-]{1}\s")
        $Line = [regex]::Split($Line,"\s[\[].*")
    if ([regex]::Match($Line,"[\\]{1}|[//]{1}").Success) {
    $Line = [regex]::Split($Line,".*[//]|.*[\\]")
    } #End if ([regex]::Match($Line,"[\]{1}|[//]{1}").Success) {
} #End if([regex]::Match($Line,".*GET.*").Success) {
```

Again, I tested this and it worked to pull out username in my environment.  Nether of these care if there are `-` or numbers in the domain or username.

Comment: Hey Nick, Thanks for your help, this almost solved all my problems. I am not going for the first solution, I didn't test it because I wanted to use regex, I feel it can be more useful and accurate for these types of things. The first if statement is handling the username or domain\username correctly, the second if statement is parsing out the username from the domain name ONLY for the case domain/username. This still leaves the case domain\username unhandled. I think it may have just been a typo on your part, you have one backslash in your if statement and two in the split.Can you explain this

Comment: The second if statement checks for a backslash or a forward slash. I tested all three and they worked no problem. The a|b in a regex means a or b. The reason for two \ is to escape it. The / doesn't need escaped.

Comment: Right, I used your exact code and it didnt work, never the less I took what you displayed of the | (or) and made my code work so thank you. But I know enough about regex to understand what your writing. So my question was. Why in the if statement do you have two forward slashes, and you do not use an escape in your back slash? This is my second if statement, similar to yours, but mine works `if(($line -match “GET”) -AND ($line -match "\s[-]{1}\s\w{1,}((\\|/)\w{1,}\b)")) { $temp = $matches[1]; $temp = $temp.TrimStart("\\|/"); }`

Comment: I tested it again at home, and it did cause problems with the `\` being alone.  All worked when I put it in with `\\`.  I have modified my answer accordingly. I tried your code, but I couldn't get anything to come out since I don't know how `$matches` is being declared.  Hope this helped.

Comment: Ahh sorry I shouldn't have assumed everyone knows what `$matches` is. $matches contains an array of matched words used with the -match and -not match operators. For more info type `get-help about_automatic_variables` in console. Im not sure if it works with your `[regex]::Match()` though, I have not tested it. Thanks for the answer!